# Sending sms programatically to one number on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, sms, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any chance to send sms only to one specified phone number?

I know that it must be executed only with native text editor (SmsComposeTask or ChatMessageManager), but is it possible to block addition of another recipients phone numbers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is basically NO.

Once you open the SMSComposeTask then basically your APP does not have any control over it. 
The user can change recipients or even the text.

If you do want this then : one way to overcome this would be to send the message from the server by connecting to a web service. So the SMS goes from the server and not from the phone.